# MongoDB shard key for emails collection

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-indexes

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.1

I have a collection that stores the emails, project-wise. The documents are as follows(haven't included the 'Raw Email Text' key for readability) :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("540d4ae7eea013be22f1f0d6"),
        "Project_Id" : "E11593",
        "Project_Name" : "National Hearing Care- Novo",
        "Email_Id" : "E11593.monitor@lntinfotech.com",
        "Date" : "Mon Sep 08 05:05:35 IST 2014",
        "To" : "manisha.bhopate@infostretch.com; ",
        "From" : "Shubhangi Thorat",
        "CC" : "NO VALUES",
        "Subject" : "RE: pics",
        "Unique_Id" : "Mon-Sep-08-11:51:20-IST-2014"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("540d4ae7eea013be22f1f0d7"),
        "Project_Id" : "E11593",
        "Project_Name" : "National Hearing Care- Novo",
        "Email_Id" : "E11593.monitor@lntinfotech.com",
        "Date" : "Mon Sep 08 05:02:38 IST 2014",
        "To" : "manisha.bhopate@infostretch.com; ",
        "From" : "Shubhangi Thorat",
        "CC" : "NO VALUES",
        "Subject" : "FW: pics",
        "Unique_Id" : "Mon-Sep-08-11:51:20-IST-2014"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("540d4ae7eea013be22f1f0d8"),
        "Project_Id" : "E11593",
        "Project_Name" : "National Hearing Care- Novo",
        "Email_Id" : "E11593.monitor@lntinfotech.com",
        "Date" : "Mon Sep 08 04:37:47 IST 2014",
        "To" : "Prachi Sutrawe; ",
        "From" : "Mahindra Shambharkar",
        "CC" : "NO VALUES",
        "Subject" : "Accepted: Show and tell -Sale",
        "Unique_Id" : "Mon-Sep-08-11:51:20-IST-2014"
}
```

I had the following thoughts on my mind when selecting the shard key:

1. Build a compound index {**Project_Id, _id**} since **Project_Id** has a low cardinality but **_id** has a high one
2. A hashed index on '**Date**' / '**Unique_Id**' which are both timestamps
3. A hashed index on '**From**' field but it's cardinality is dependent on the no. of people involved in the project
4. '**To**' and '**CC**' are multivalue keys and '**Subject**' has high randomness so not sure if these keys can be used at all
5. While not listed in the output, '**Raw_Text**' will be extensively read by different applications but I'm not sure if an index should be built and even used in sharding for this key !

What will be the optimal shard key in this case ?

Comment: Please add some informations about queries you will be doing in this application - the most used ones.

Comment: As far as this collection is concerned, writes(data insertion) and reads(all keys) will be involved